# Off topic reason for questions that don't include code?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, off-topic, close-reasons

Currently, one of the two custom off topic reasons for CR is:

> Questions must contain *working* code for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

Technically, this does include questions that don't include code at all, or just link to it ([latest example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/27909/2041)), but I think it's confusing in those cases, especially the emphasis on “working” (which makes sense in other cases).

Do you think it would be worth it to have a separate close reason for this case? Or should I just use the free-text option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed new close reason has been added.

Comment: Hope I'm not being too picky/pedantic, but there's a grammatical error (comma splice at `itself, the code`), and the wording could be a bit better in my opinion: *Questions must include the code you want reviewed. Code must not appear only in a link to an external source. Doing so makes us dependent on a third party and makes it harder to review your code. If your code is very large, please select only the portions in which you are especially interested in a review. You are encouraged to keep the link to the rest of your code.*

Comment: Was the new close reason removed? I don't see it anymore.

Answer (score 8):

I think adding this as a common close reason is a great idea. Needing to close questions for this reason is pretty common.

Suggested wording:

> Questions must include the code you want reviewed
>   in the question itself, the code must not appear only in a link to an
>   external source. Doing so makes us dependent on a third party and makes it harder to review your code. If your code is very large, please select portions
>   you are especially interested in a review on and post those. You are
>   encouraged to keep the link to the rest of your code.

Comment: Yeah, this wording seems okay to me (certainly better than what I had in mind).

Comment: +1. Maybe some reasoning about why it is important couble be also useful.

Comment: +1, good suggestion. I think it would be nice to mention [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) as well.

Comment: @Lstor, as a community we haven't emphasize SSCCE. I think we'd want to decide on the community level to emphasize that for it to make sense to include in the close reason.

Comment: @palacsint, hmm..., I'm not sure how much we could put into the reason there that would explain it. Any thoughts what exactly to put in?